# merging to master deletes new files

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I want to try to merge a branch to master. The problem is that a lot of files are in the changed file list and lots of files wil be changed wrong.

4 things that i see that are not right:

- Some new files wil be deleted in master (files are created in master after the branch was made)
- Some new files have conflicts on delete (files are created in master after branch was made)
- Some new files wil be changed (some lines wil be deleted so i guess some commits will be reverted) (files are created in master after the brach was made)
- Changed files in master wil be undone or partly undone after merge (I did not touch these files in the branch)

How we got this branch was the following:

We created a branch from master and did everything that needed to be done. (lets call it a)
We created a second branch(b) from master did here some stuff and created a branch from this one(c)
We merged a into c.
Now we want to merge c into master but the above problems occure

If there is anymore info you need before you can help me I am happy to give it to you just ask.

If you have any idea I would be very happy because looking over 2000 files isn't doing it for me.

Comment: when you branch off from branch-A and branch-B is it from the same commit?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should keep your branch A-C updated by a merge or rebase.

Try to `git rebase master` to your branch C. This does not guarantee that there will be no conflicts though.

Comment: Thanks i tried rebasing but there were over 400 commits to rebase with almost all of them conflics that where hard to solve because it was code from a lot of people.